# Invoke a generic method for properties which are known at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics, reflection

```
public partial class ReturnHeader
{
        public int ReturnHeaderId { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceNo { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ReturnDetail> ReturnDetails { get; set; }
}

public void TraverseThroughClass<T> (T entity) where T : class
{
 try
 {
  var type = typeof(T);
  PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();
  foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
  {
   if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
  {
```

> This check determines whether the property is a list or not.
>
> **Issue 1: if true, cast it into list or any collection.**
>   What i want to do is if property is a collection cast it and for each item in casted collection call `TraverseThroughClass`

```
    /* Error casting into any collection*/
    //var propertiesValues = prop.GetValue(entity) as IList;
    var listType = GetCollectionItemType(prop.PropertyType);
    foreach (var listItem in propertiesValues)
    {
```

> **Issue 2:For each item in collection call TraverseThroughClass (T entity)**

```
    }
  }
  else
  {
   Console.WriteLine("Prop Name : " + prop.Name + " Prop Value : " 
            + prop.GetValue(entity, null));
  }
}
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
  throw;
 }
}     

 public static Type GetCollectionItemType(Type collectionType)
 {
  var types = collectionType.GetInterfaces()
            .Where(x => x.IsGenericType
                && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
            .ToArray();
        return types.Length == 1 ? types[0].GetGenericArguments()[0] : null;
    }
```

Comment: A `string` is an `IEnumerable<Char>`. You find that surprising?

Comment: I am not an expert like you @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Thanks for letting me know by the way. I'll update the question.

Comment: `comparedEntityHashSets.Add(entity.GetHashCode());` - that smells. Different entities are allowed to have the same hashcodes. Why not just add `entity` to the HashSet?

Comment: I'll remove that. Ignore that part.

Comment: I'm not actually clear on what the question is here. I don't see a single question mark in your question, for example.

Comment: `ReturnHeader` has `ICollection<ReturnDetail>`. What i want is if traverse method is called it should go deep to traverse. Bu my problem is 1st i am unable to cast the `ICollection<ReturnDetail>` in runtime and then call `Traverse` for `ReturnDetail`.

Comment: You don't have a method called `Traverse`. Do you mean `TraverseThroughClass`? I think it would help if you made a [mcve], which we could actually run.

Comment: It's actually `TraverseThroughClass`. Sorry. This method will run fine, i think @canton7

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're attempting to cast an `ICollection` as an `IList`, which may or may not work. The value of the property at runtime could be an `ICollection` that doesn't implement `IList`.

If the runtime value of this property implements `IList` it will work, but if not it will fail.

```
public virtual ICollection<ReturnDetail> ReturnDetails { get; set; }
```

Since you're checking to see if the property type is assignable from `IEnumerable`, let's just be consistent and use that everywhere.

Another confusion is that `TraverseThroughClass` takes an `entity` parameter, but in the above statement you're using `this` to invoke the property. Do you mean to invoke the property on `entity`? That would make more sense. Otherwise it's switching - part of the method is invoking properties of the `entity` and part is invoking the property on `this`, which is the class instance in which the method is getting called.

To clear that up, I'm moving `TraverseThroughClass` into its own static class, and performing all operations on the `entity` argument. I also removed `GetCollectionItemType`. It's called, but the result of the call is never used, so it doesn't look like we need it.

Here's a modified version of your method, moved into its own class. (Note that I'm not addressing the bigger picture of what this attempts to do, just trying to get past the issue in your question.)

```
public static class Traversal
{
    public static void TraverseThroughClass<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
            {
                var propertiesValues = prop.GetValue(entity);

                // What if the property value is null?
                if (propertiesValues == null) continue;
                var collection = propertiesValues as IEnumerable;
                foreach (var listItem in collection)
                {
                    // I don't know what you want to do with these. 
                    // I'm just confirming that we're able to inspect them.
                    Debug.WriteLine("Success, we're iterating over the items!!"); 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Prop Name : " + prop.Name + " Prop Value : "
                                  + prop.GetValue(entity, null));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That still leaves the detail that your method will traverse `InvoiceNo` since it implements `IEnumerable` (it's a collection of characters.) If you don't want to do that you could specifically exclude strings or be more specific about what types you *do* want to traverse.

At this point I can execute this code:

```
var returnHeader = new ReturnHeader
{
    ReturnDetails = new List<ReturnDetail>(
        new ReturnDetail[] { new ReturnDetail(), new ReturnDetail() }),
    InvoiceNo = "Invoice!"
};
Traversal.TraverseThroughClass(returnHeader);
```

...and the traversal will iterate over both the characters in `InvoiceNo` and the items in `ReturnDetails`.

Comment: I'll test it tommorrow in office. So far your `IEnumerable` thing makes sense. But the other issue is yet there i need to call `TraverseThroughClass` for each item too. I don't know whether my analogy is correct or not but i guess i can say generic imlementation of DFS.

Comment: Writing untyped code that uses reflection to traverse complex objects with nested collections is a pain. One day you'll need a dictionary or something else and then you'll have to account for that too. You may find that it's much, much easier to write methods for individual classes. You'll have to write specific code for properties and collections, but unless you're dealing with lots and lots of types it's probably quicker and easier.

Comment: i am feeling the pain but it's kind of need because it has to be implemented at too many places. So i thought of going with generics. If it gets too messy , i'll move to the easy approach but i want to try it as if it's successful, it will save me lot of  effort.

Comment: I edited my comment because I said "generics" but didn't mean "generics." I was thinking more of code that tries to account for every type of property.